# Angular 1.6 Error: GET http://127.0.0.1:56035/[url] 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe

I am working on a project and been stuck for almost a couple times already.

So I have a file that needs to show an iframe video player with the embed of youtube. So I did use interpolation w/c is I think that its pulling up the right URL:

```
<div class="video-player">
  <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" ng-src="{{'www.youtube.com/embed/' + $ctrl.video.id.videoId}}" allowFullScreen></iframe>
  </div>
  <div class="video-player-details">
    <h3>{{$ctrl.video.snippet.title}}</h3>
    <div>{{$ctrl.video.snippet.description}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, for some reason whenever I run my code I always get this error on the console:

```
angular.js:3626 GET http://127.0.0.1:56035/www.youtube.com/embed/OPxeCiy0RdY 404 (Not Found)
```

What's weird here is that when I tried to check the elements code on the inspector tool after the program runs, it adds a #document property with another HTML tags inside the iframe:

```
<iframe class="embed-responsive-item" ng-src="www.youtube.com/embed/OPxeCiy0RdY" allowfullscreen="" src="www.youtube.com/embed/OPxeCiy0RdY">
   #document

   <html><head></head><body>Cannot GET /www.youtube.com/embed/OPxeCiy0RdY
   </body></html>

</iframe>
```

I am wondering what's causing this error and why it doesn't show the actual video in the player. I have two more files that I can post here that might be responsible for the error. First one is index.js and the 2nd one is the videoPlayer.js:

index.js:

```
angular.module('video-player', [])
.config(function($sceDelegateProvider) {
  $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist([
    'self',
    'https://www.youtube.com/**',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search'
  ])
});
```

Here's the videoPlayer.js:

```
angular.module('video-player')

.component('videoPlayer', {
  bindings: {
   video: '<'
  },
   templateUrl: 'src/templates/videoPlayer.html'
});
```

I hope someone could point out what am I doing wrong here. I've tried my very best to trouble shoot I don't find any means to know where the error is and why it's causing us not show the actual iframe.

PS: We use [`live-server`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/live-server) for our server

Comment: You may change `ng-src="www.youtube.com/embed/OPxeCiy0RdY"` by `ng-src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/OPxeCiy0RdY"` ?

Comment: @Striped: I did that already but I got another error: angular.js:14800 Error: [$interpolate:interr] Can't interpolate: {{'https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + $ctrl.video.id.videoId}}
Error: [$sce:insecurl] Blocked loading resource from url not allowed by $sceDelegate policy.  URL: https://www.youtube.com/embed/OPxeCiy0RdY
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.9/$sce/insecurl

Comment: take note we're dynamically putting the video ID here via $ctrl.video.id.videoId.

Answer (score 0):

After I've read your second comment on this post, I believe you can resolve your issue by doing something like this and also make sure you set your url as @Striped suggested:

```
<iframe id="iframe" ng-src="{{$ctrl.redirectUrl | trusted}}">
   <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
```

Where $ctrl.redirectUrl is set somewhere in your controller like this:

```
$ctrl.redirectUrl = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XIJHg1XWR7o";
```

And then create the trusted filter:

```
app.filter('trusted', ['$sce', function ($sce) {
  return function (url) {
    return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(url);
  };
}]);
```

Let me know if it helps.